# Unable to import google cloud library in aws glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-bigquery, aws-glue

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=PROJECT_ID, location="US")
table_id = projectname + table_name
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=1,
                                    autodetect=True, )
```

**Error - AttributeError: module 'google' has no attribute 'cloud'**
I have added google lib egg file in python library path but still it throws error